# How to get duplicate text values from SQL query

Tags: sql

I have to get table only with duplicate text values using SQL query. I have used `Having count(columnname) > 1` but I'm not getting result, only with duplicate values instead getting all values.

Can anyone suggest whether I have to add anything to my query?

Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and provide:  (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) the query you are currently using; (4) a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: You have to get *table*? Are you sure you want to get table and not rows inside the table?

Comment: Please share your work done till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below query. mention the column which is getting duplicated in the patition by clause..

```
with CTE_1
AS
(SELECT *,COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(yourDuplicateColumn,' ',''))) Order by -anycolunm- ) cnt
 FROM YourTable
 )
SELECT *
FROM CTE_1
WHERE cnt>1
```

Comment: Thanks. This is getting result what I need. but a bit space issue. sample data in text column have values TextColumn : AsdaSTORES, AsdaSTORES        , Dynamic Motor, Dynamic Motor         . when there is space at last of the word the rows are not matching as duplicates. I think I need to add RTRIM or LTRIM to the column. please suggest

Comment: if you wanted to remove the space from your text data,use REPLACE function..use the updated code..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` is a primary key

```
select *
from myTable t1
where exists (select 1 
                 from myTable t2
                 where t2.text = t1.text and t2.id != t1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar to following query:

```
SELECT
  column1, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY column1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```